# SQLAlchemy Match Against clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have MySQL table with full-text index. I want to know how to use MATCH ... AGAINST() with SQLAlchemy. Do you have some examples?

```
...
    trs = dbsession.query(Trans).filter(Trans.client_id==user_id)
    if search and search != '':
        trs = trs.filter(or_(Trans.transcribe.like('%'+search+'%'), Trans.lang_name.like('%'+search+'%')))
...
```

I want to replace LIKE with 'MATCH/AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE' construction but I don't know how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply need to use the clause:

```
Trans.lang_name.match(str_to_match)
```

where `str_to_match` is the string you want to match.

This compiles (for the MySQL dialects) to (assuming the `Trans` model table name is `trans` and the model attributes match the column names):

```
'MATCH(trans.lang_name) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)' % str_to_match
```

Comment: As you can see in the [SQLAlchemy source code](https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/a2dae1bdc9fa/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py?at=default#cl-1281), the current implrmentation of the `MATCH` operator is hard-coded for `BOOLEAN MODE` so I am afraid it is not possible to switch modes with the current version. Maybe a good opportunity to contribute a patch to the project to support alternative modes? :)

Comment: Thanks Pedro! It's really useful to check the source code from time to time :)